# Conanfile.txt structure

Tags: conan

I have the following requires section in a conanfile.txt

```
[requires]
openssl/1.0.2g/stable
openssl/1.1.1d/stable
```

Usually each line has a structure name/version@owner/channel, I see in this case the channel is missing so the `@` was not added, so I want to know if the structure is correct in case we don't have an owner or it should be `openssl/1.1.1d@stable`?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of misconceptions in that `conanfile.txt`:

- You cannot depend on more than one `openssl` version at a time, that is a version conflict and will throw an error. You need 2 separate conanfiles, each one with its installation in order to do that.
- Both the user and channel are mandatory if either of both is going to be defined, and always with the `@`. The only shortened version is the one without user *and* channel, like `openssl/1.1.1a`

Comment: For more info: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile_txt.html

Comment: is there any doc that says about the owner/channel and that they have to be always present (both)? not only one?